# Is it possible to display views dynamically based on the data retrieved ? If yes, how?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. So please help me in this. 
I have a scenario like this :

There are 3 categories with checkboxes
Category 1
Category 2
Category 3

Each category has few questions. 
Category 1 - question 1, question 2
Category 2 - question 1, question 2, question 3
Category 3 - question 1, question 2

NOTE : question 1 is same in all categories, question 2 is same in all categories.

Now Select category 1 and category 2, related questions will be displayed as shown below :

Question 1
Answer 1 : enter answer here

Question 2
Answer 2 : enter answer here

Question 3
Answer 3 : enter answer here

Here all answer fields has different type of input boxes, like text field for question 1,  date field for question 2, upload file for question 3.

Now my question is :

How to display those input fields for different questions which are coming from database based on category selection ?

I am able to get questions correctly ,  but the issue is in displaying input fields for those questions.

Is this approach of getting questions from database, correct? Or is there any other best procedure to do this?

I am using laravel 5.2 with angularjs for frontend

Please explain me...

Comment: You might need to add a column in your table to check what type of question is this. This would help you to check for the input type in the blade.

Comment: But question will be created by admin, we can't guess the question type always. Even we get which type the question is,  we can't write the code for input field on view as the questions are displayed using foreach loop.

Comment: Based on my interpretation of the question, I think @Jilson has the right idea - when your admins create questions, they should also define the type of question. Otherwise there really is no way for you to know what to render. Then when you pull the questions from the database and loop through them, you can switch on the type of question in order to render the appropriate element.

Comment: Yup I am trying in that way...let me check...  Thankyou guyz for your comments